# Send ip address to my email when it is changed

Tags: curl, ip-address, sendmail, remote-access

I'm working remotely on my office machine and I would like to get an email with the new ip address when it is changed. I have told once that I can do that using `curl` but I could not find anything on how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a lot more than curl.

You could certainly use curl to grab `https://www.whatismyip.com`, but you will need some sort of scripting language (or compiled language) to parse that, extract the IP address and then check to see if it's different.

Comment: If I was to run a .sh script everyday do I have to inset it in the bash file?

Comment: Yes... In addition to writing all of the supporting code to extract the IP and check if it changed.  You may find something like Python or Ruby much easier since they have libraries for grabbing and parsing web pages while Bash does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use bash for it, you could install mailutils.

```
apt-get install mailutils
```

Then just get ifconfig data and send it using it.
Here's a tutorial http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-command-examples/

In Python you could do something along those lines:

```
import socket
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

email_from = "script@email.com"
email_to = "youremail@email.com"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("google.com", 80))
ipaddress = s.getsockname()[0]
s.close()

msg = MIMEText(ipaddress)
msg['Subject'] = 'Your current IP ADDRESS %s' % ipaddress
msg['From'] = email_from
msg['To'] = email_to

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(email_from, [email_to], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

And in PHP:

```
<?php

$message = "Current IP ADDRESS: " . get_ip();

$email_to = "youremail@email.com";

mail($email_to, $message, $message);

function get_ip($destination='64.0.0.0', $port=80)
{
  $s = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
  socket_connect($s, $destination, $port);
  socket_getsockname($s, $ipaddress, $port);
  socket_close($s);
  return $ipaddress;
}

?>
```

Then just crontab it, or wrap it in While True, create global_variable with your current ipaddress as of script start and if does not match your current ip, then mail.
Sadly if your PC has more then one ip, there are problems with PHP's $_SERVER[] variables. Thats a workaround in this case.

Edit: Other way in PHP

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://whatismyipaddress.com/');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
    if(preg_match('/\/\/whatismyipaddress.com\/ip\/(.*)/', $element->href, $match))
        $ipaddress = $match[1];
}

$email_to = "youremail@email.com";
$message = "Current IP ADDRESS: " . $ipaddress;

mail($email_to, $message, $message)

?>
```

To use it you need http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.
Also using https pages requires changes in php.ini, so I changed the page to the first one google found for me whatismyipaddress.com.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's very likely that the OP is behind a NAT firewall.  In this case the IP will never be what shows up on the box.  At least, that's how I read the question.

Comment: Edited my answer and added way around using DOM traversal parser. Don't have much experience with NAT, but if curl would work, then this should also.